# Can the voiceless velar fricative, [x], be represented in Japanese?

Tags: japanese, polish, velar, fricatives

I was specifically thinking of whether the voiceless velar fricative [x] as in Polish could be represented in Japanese, but [x] would be the same or very similar in every language which contains it, right?

Anyway, just wondering. Off the top of my head I can't think of a way, nor find one by perusing the IPA for Japanese article or online books.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate"? In the normal meaning of "translate", *hito* translates *person* and vice versa -- they mean the same thing. Japanese does not have [x], and the Polish velar fricative does not mean anything (sounds do not mean things, they are elements of words, which mean things).

Comment: What about ⟨x⟩ within a name?

Comment: AFAIK Japanese does not have [x] in names. Anyhow, what would it mean to translate *x* in a name?

Comment: Take, for example, the surname _Ba**ch**_.

Comment: See my answer for Bach and a bunch of other examples.

Comment: Thank you. Before properly reading your answer, I stole the example of _Bach_ to see what @user6726 would say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that by "translate" you mean which syllables in words loaned by Japanese correspond to [x] in their source language.

The answer is that words containing [x] which come directly from languages with that phoneme are sometimes rendered ッハ *hha*. The most common examples would be Bach バッハ *Bahha* and Mach マッハ *Mahha*.

Other times, it is simply rendered ハ (cf [Zakharov](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B6%E3%83%8F%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95) *Zaharofu*, [Halacha](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC) ハラーハー), or particularly word-finally, フ (cf [Lech Wałęsa](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%95%E3%83%BB%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5) *Refu Vawensa*). Note that while ending not in /x/ but /h/, the Arabic name for God is sometimes transcribed as アッラーフ *Arrafu*.

Words of Greek origin beginning in Greek with χ, however, tend to have that sound represented instead with syllables from the か行 (*k-* syllables), in line with English.

Another subtlety is that the German orthographic **ch** which before high vowels is a palatal fricative [ç] and not a velar [x] is almost universally transcribed as ッヒ *hhi*, as in アルベリッヒ *Aruberihhi* for "Alberich".

Comment: I don't think "transcribe" is correct either, since Japanese speakers do not transcribe words, except a handful who are linguists. Rendering a foreign language letter sequence vaguely believed to have some h-like quality is not even phoneme-adaptation, unless done by a Japanese speaker who is actually hearing a Polish speaker utter <ch>.

Comment: True, "transcribe" is not correct either, as the goal is not fidelity. However I believe this is what the OP wants to know -- how loan words containing [x] in their source language are rendered in the target language. I will edit the answer to skirt the terminology issue.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to know. However, do inform me of why _transcribe_ is incorrect here, in case there is a way of properly rewording my question.

Comment: The goal of transcription is to, ideally, map one-to-one from phonemes  in a source language into some unambiguous representation in a target writing system. For instance, if I wanted to represent American Sign Language in a way that records it faithfully, I might use something like [SignWriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignWriting), which ideally would allow me to map the source language into a written form and then back again. When a language loans words containing sounds it does not have, the mapping may not necessarily be faithful. Hope this helps.

Comment: When the Japanese writing system really needs to (properly speaking) *transcribe* sounds that the standard language doesn't have (for instance when linguists are doing Ainu work or transcribing Japanese dialects), [here's an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_scripts) of what it tends to do.

Comment: Thank you. And it seems based on the article that transcriptions such as those exist in a few different forms, so that there is no direct consensus?

Comment: Yes. Some Japanese linguists, in order to represent non-standard phonemes, do things like adding 半濁点、濁点 to kana syllables which cannot take them in the standard syllabary. Because there is no standard way to interpret such combinations that do not exist in standard kana, they are free to assign whatever interpretation they want. There is, however, [this occasionally encountered convention](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32622/dakuten-used-in-non-standard-ways-like-with-vowels).

Comment: Are there any existing examples of such transcriptions? [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292927109_Transcription_of_Polish_words_into_Katakana_A_study_on_perception_of_word_stress) seems to represent what I mean, but I can't access the full text.

Comment: Unfortunately this article is about representing Polish stress (which correlates generally in Japanese with vowel length, as Japanese itself doesn't have stress) and not about representing Polish consonants. To my knowledge there is no standard unambiguous way to represent [x] in kana.

Comment: Fair enough. ッハ seems like a perfect representation anyway. The only difference I can discern is that it adds an _a_ sound at the end. But that tends to happen to many loan words as is.

Comment: Strangely, *a* is actually a very unusual epenthetic vowel in Japanese loan words. The usual one is *u*, with *i* and *o* in other specific conditioning contexts.

Comment: Oh, interesting. If you try to pronounce [x] on its own, I suppose it does sound like ッハ, or more specifically, _hhə_.

Comment: @MadBanners If you're happy with it, would be grateful if you could accept this answer.

Comment: Apologies, done now. I'm aware that Polish has a similar (I think) convention to German where the voiceless velar fricative is voiced depending on which obstruent precedes or succeeds it. Would this affect Japanese representation? (Based on your example of _Alberich_.)

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_orthography) Polish orthographic < ch > only represents [x] (and apparently also [ɣ] "if voiced"? I wasn't aware of this). If this isn't correct I'd be curious to know what other realisations there are.

Comment: There's a seemingly more detailed explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Polish). A bit dense for me, but apparently "voiceless obstruents are voiced (/x/ becoming [ɣ], etc.) in clusters ending in any voiced obstruent except /v, ʐ/, which are then themselves devoiced."

Comment: I don't know enough Polish, but that just means that clusters of the form /x/ + voiced stop, for instance <chd> (if it exists in Polish), would be realised [ɣd] rather than [xd] or [xt], and that orthographic <chrz> or <chw> are resistant to this voicing and become [xʂ] and [xf] respectively. What would happen in Japanese? This is entirely speculation but either 1) the allophony would not be reflected in the loan or 2) it would be realised with the が行 (*g-* series).

Comment: Are those voiced obstruents mentioned in the article the only ones? Also, does this rule transcend words, i.e. if a word ends in <ch>?

Comment: You would have to ask a linguist of Polish -- my own knowledge of Polish phonology is limited.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I'll try to get an answer in the comments section of my other Linguistics question — feel free to tag along if you're interested.